# How can I disable model validation for one model type in WebApi?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi endpoint that takes a `MailMessage` object (from System.Net). I've defined custom JsonConverters so that MailMessage deserializes properly. However, I'm running it into an issue because the `DefaultBodyModelValidator` traverses the object graph and tries to access a property on a `Stream` object in one of the attachments, which fails. How can I disable this traversal for the MailMessage class and everything under it?

Comment: Why would you be receiving a MailMessage in a WebApi request?  MailMessage is not intended for that purpose.  You should instead be using a model of your own design, which may look like a MailMessage but is completely in your control.  It never ceases to amaze me the amount of work people will create for themselves in a futile attempt to reduce work.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch: I did consider the approach of building a custom model. MailMessage is a pre-built 'model' of an email that serializes quite nicely to and from JSON without much additional work. I could build my own model that entirely replicates MailMessage, and then write a mapper from MailMessage to that model and back, but that seems unecessarily complex

Comment: MailMessage is not marked as Serializable for a reason, it's deliberately not considered as such.  You should not use classes that are not designed for this purpose in that way.  This will almost surely come back to bite you, but you're obviously free to do 3x more work to save yourself some time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found at least one way to do this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SuppressModelValidationJsonConverter))]
public sealed class SuppressModelValidation<TValue>
{
    private readonly TValue _value;

    public SuppressModelValidation(TValue value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    // this must be a method, not a property, or otherwise WebApi will validate
    public TValue GetValue()
    {
        return this._value;
    }
}

internal sealed class SuppressModelValidationJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // GetGenericArguments(Type) from http://www.codeducky.org/10-utilities-c-developers-should-know-part-two/
        return objectType.GetGenericArguments(typeof(SuppressModelValidation<>)).Length > 0;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var valueType = objectType.GetGenericArguments(typeof(SuppressModelValidation<>)).Single();

        var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, valueType);
        return value != null ? Activator.CreateInstance(objectType, value) : null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the controller, I then have:

```
    public Task Send([FromBody] SuppressModelValidation<MailMessage> message)
    {
        // do stuff with message.GetValue();
    }
```